# managed resource service account key has not been declared in module error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```js
### main.tf
resource "google_service_account" "mstr_bq_sa" {
  account_id = "sa-${var.env}-common-${var.sa_index}"
  project    = var.project_id
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "mstr_bq_sa_key" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.mstr_bq_sa.name
  public_key_type    = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE"
 
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "mstr_bq_secret" {
  secret_id = google_service_account_key.mstr_bq_sa_key.name
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
   project = var.project_id
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "key_secret_version" {
  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.mstr_bq_secret.id
  secret_data = base64decode(google_service_account_key.mstr_bq_key.private_key)
}


###module
module "m_bq_connection" {
  source            = "../../modules/mstbq"
  #env               = lookup(local.envs, var.environment, "dev")
  sa_index          = var.sa_index
  project_id        = var.project_id
  application_title = "MSTR Access"
  support_email     = "abc@gmail.com"
  client_display_name  = "abc Client"  
}
```

I get the foll. error when i run terraform apply, why am i getting the error

> Error: Reference to undeclared resource │ │   on
> ....\modules\m-bq\service_account.tf line 22, in resource
> "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "key_secret_version": │   22:
> secret_data =
> base64decode(google_service_account_key.mstr_bq_key.private_key) │ │ A
> managed resource "google_service_account_key" "mstr_bq_key" has not
> been │ declared in module.mstr_bq_connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear: `mstr_bq_key` does not exist. Probably you need to use `mstr_bq_sa_key` which you actually create in your code.